# iOS Facebook SDK login page shows before protected page

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

In my application, I am testing out the Facebook SDK to use "Login using Facebook" feature. I was able to create a button to login using Facebook and it takes me to the protected page.

I am also using [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] to stay logged in. However, the login page appears for 1 second before navigating to the protected page.

Below is my code in View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    // Facebook Access Token
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        ProtectedPageViewController *pp = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProtectedPageViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pp animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well... that was easy.

Just set the animated to NO

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pp animated:NO];
```